# iCarousel + Parse: Loading Async Images from PFObject

Tags: ios7, parse-platform, icarousel

I am trying to populate an iCarousel with a parse (parse.com, pfoject) object without success.

I can't find any example of how to do it, so it why i am asking here...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

_items = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"testUser"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects
        [_items addObjectsFromArray:objects];

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];


//configure carousel
_carousel.type = iCarouselTypeRotary;

//_carousel.viewpointOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 100.0f);
[_carousel setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, -60.0f)];
```

}

And at viewForItemAtIndex:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300.0f, 300.0f)];
    }

PFObject *eachObject = [_items objectAtIndex:index];
PFFile *theImage = [eachObject objectForKey:@"image"];
NSData *imageData = [theImage getData];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

return view;
```

}

Please, any help? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad, After the

```
   [_items addObjectsFromArray:objects];
```

Put

```
 [_carousel reloadData];
```

Otherwise the carousel won't be updated after the items have been added to the array, so you'll still be looking at an empty carousel.